# Nav Items Going to Sections Not Working

Tags: html

I have a navigation menu for a single page (just scrolls down to each section) which looks like:

```
<li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></il>
      <li><a href="#fund">About the Fund</a></li>
      <li><a href="#managers">About the Managers</a></li>
```

and corresponding sections which look like:

```
<section id="about-us">...</section>
<section id="fund">...</section>
<section id="managers">...</section>
```

No matter which one I click on, it just goes to the 'about us' section. Any ideas why this isn't working? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You ended the about `</li>` with `</il>`

```
<li><a href="#about-us">About Us</a></il>
```

Comment: Works fine when I test it out: http://jsfiddle.net/6eb7bew1/
Maybe you forgot to close a tag on some of your other HTML.